# Selecting rows and updating them in the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've implemented a job queue in PHP & MySQL (which works with multiple scripts running in parallel) by having two queries: the first updates rows in the table with an update ID value, then the second retrieves the rows with this value. The two queries are performed inside of a transaction to prevent other scripts running in parallel from retrieving the same rows.

The first query looks like this:

```
UPDATE products p
SET p.update_id = '550b8d7f3ba477.82670719', p.date_update_started = UTC_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE p.id IN
(
    SELECT p2.id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT p3.id
        FROM products p3
        WHERE p3.date_update_started < UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR # only allow the product processed if not selected for processing recently
                    AND p3.updated = 1
        ORDER BY p3.some_date ASC
    ) p2
)
LIMIT 100
```

Then the second query would simply retrieve the rows with the update ID.

The above query takes 0.4 seconds to execute on a table with 100k rows. The performance worries me because the table will grow to tens or hundreds of millions of rows over time.

Can this query be changed somehow to make it more efficient?

EDIT: The storage engine is InnoDB and the table has 22 indexes on it.

Comment: Is the date_update_started indexed? The slower than expected time could also be time it takes to update the indexes that are being changed by the update.

Comment: @Bob Yes, and there's also an index on `date_update_started,updated`. The latter is what MySQL is using according to EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this not work the same?

```
UPDATE products
SET update_id = '550b8d7f3ba477.82670719', 
    date_update_started = UTC_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE date_update_started < UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
    AND updated = 1
ORDER BY some_date
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: I *think* it does work the same. Now that I think about it, the reason I used the ugly structure in my query is that I had a GROUP BY statement in the innermost SELECT subquery. Rewriting the query to your method reduces the execution time from 0.4 seconds to 0.3 seconds. Better, but I'm still confused why it's taking so long.